# PySpark: Grouping elements in a list

Tags: python, pyspark

Desired output-[((1,2),(3,4),5)]

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5])
rdd.map(lambda x: ((x[0],x[1]),(x[2],x[3]),x[4])).collect()
```

However, I get the error --

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:592)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:575)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
```

Please correct the code. I am using Python with Spark

Comment: If you want to have a list per row, pass a list of lists when constructing the rdd like this `rdd = sc.parallelize([[1,2,3,4,5]])`

Comment: thanks Ali. It helped me in clearing my basics and your solution worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

As per Mohamed Ali JAMAOUI's comment:

"If you want to have a list per row, pass a list of lists when constructing the rdd like this rdd = sc.parallelize([[1,2,3,4,5]])"